# `CakeResponse` referencing undefined variables in `compact()` call triggers errors/notices

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.x, cakephp-2.9

I’m updating my first CakePHP application on a web server, but pages show errors which are at the end of this post. I can’t find the file(s) which have not uploded correctly. Thanks for help.

CakePHP version : **2.9**

Error messages :

> Notice (8): compact(): Undefined variable: etagMatches [CORE/Cake/Network/CakeResponse.php, line 1171]*

> Notice (8): compact() [function.compact]: Undefined variable: timeMatches [CORE/Cake/Network/CakeResponse.php, line 1171]*

> Notice (8): compact() [function.compact]: Undefined variable: subject [CORE/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php, line 128]*

Comment: I think you are going to have to look at all the error mesages in your logs

Comment: When upgrading, it is not sufficient to just copy the new files. Read the migration guide for step by step instructions.

Answer (score 8):

As of PHP 7.3 `compact()` will trigger an error when referencing undefined variables.

This has been fixed in CakePHP 2.10.13, either upgrade your application (preferred), or downgrade your PHP version.

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/12487**

Comment: I have just downgraded the PHP version of the server and I no longer have this error. Thank you

Comment: Or you can hack the framework https://infinitbility.com/undefined-variable-timematches-and-etagmatches-cakephp/